# Process unicode string in C and Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macos, unicode

I write a C function to read characters in an user-input string. Because this string is user-input, so it can contains any unicode characters. There's an Objective C method receives the user-input NSString, then convert this string to NSData and pass this data to the C function for processing. The C function searches for these symbol characters: *, [, ], _, it doesn't care any other characters. Everytime it found one of the symbols, it processes and then calls an Objective C method, pass the location of the symbol.

C code:

```
typedef void (* callback)(void *context, size_t location);

void process(const uint8_t *data, size_t length, callback cb, void *context)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        if (data[i] == '*' || data[i] == '[' || data[i] == ']' || data[i] == '_')
        {
            int valid = 0;
            //do something, set valid = 1

            if (valid)
                cb(context, i);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Objective C code:

```
//a C function declared in .m file
void mycallback(void *context, size_t location)
{
    [(__bridge id)context processSymbolAtLocation:location];
}

- (void)processSymbolAtLocation:(NSInteger)location
{
    NSString *result = [self.string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, 1)];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}

- (void)processUserInput:(NSString*)string
{
    self.string = string;
    //convert string to data
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //pass data to C function
    process(data.bytes, data.length, mycallback, (__bridge void *)(self));
}
```

The code works fine if the input string contains only English characters. If it contains composed character sequences, multibyte characters or other unicode characters, the result string in `processSymbolAtLocation` method is not the expected symbol.

How to convert the NSString object to NSData correctly? How to get the correct location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you start off with a UTF-16 encoded `NSString` and produce a sequence of UTF-8 encoded bytes. The number of code units required to represent a string in UTF-16 may not be equal to that number required to represent it in UTF-8, so the offsets in your two forms may not match - as you have found out.

Why are you using C to scan the string for matches in the first place? You might want to look at `NSString`'s `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:` method which you can use to find the next occurrence of character from your set.

If you need to use C then convert your string into a sequence of UTF-16 words and use `uint16_t` on the C side.

HTH

Comment: If I change to NSUTF16StringEncoding in ObjC and uint16_t in C, how to loop through the data and check for the symbol character? And how to calculate the correct offset? Thank you!

Comment: If you use `NSUTF16StringEncoding` then the result will start with two bytes of BOM and you need to skip them, e.g. something like `data.bytes+2`. Or you can use `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding` to specify the byte-order and the BOM will not be included. The number of 16-bit words is half the size of your buffer in bytes, e.g. something like `data.length/2`, and subtract one if there is a BOM. Apart from changing the type the C function needs no change - in C a "character" constant is actually of type `int` (and `char` is an integral type) so everything just works as before.

Comment: So data.length (- 2 if NSUTF16StringEncoding) is **always** double of string.length, right?

Comment: Ignoring any BOM, yes. Each character in an `NSString` is a `unichar`, which is a UTF16 code unit. So when you convert an `NSString` to an `NSData` using a UTF16 encoding the most that changes is the possible addition of a BOM and the endian order of each 16-bit value - the number of 16-bit values doesn't change.

Comment: I use NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding and make changes as you suggested, it works fine. Thank you very much!